# Putting a delay when using asynchronous socket methods

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I am using C#, .Net Framework 3.5 for software development. My application connects to multiple clients over TCP/IP at once and collects some data from them. The client number is very high(**over 100**). Before my application development process, i have done some researches and seen that i must use asynchronous sockets implementation for the performance and manageability aspects.

It seems OK for now but i am currently searching for the best way putting a delay just before sending a data to clients. My application sometimes needs to wait around 2 seconds to send a specific data. For now, i just put a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);` code line before asynchronous send method. Is this the convenient way or is there any better way to that? Does this `Sleep` function block my main thread of application or does it block only the thread of asynchronous socket belongs.

Comment: may we know the reason for the required delay? It seems a bit odd to deliberately put a delay in

Comment: @AlastairPitts i put the delay because client machines needs a delay after some operations. They do not response any commands within a few seconds.

Comment: a better alternative is buffering the data on client-side and consuming the data once client is ready for so. an asnyc tcp (or whatever) client way to go.

Comment: @HuseyinUslu thanks for your idea. But buffering is irrelevant with my case. i dont need to buffer anything, i just need to wait for some seconds just before sending the data over tcp. i looked for a built-in .NET solution but i am afraid i need to implement my own solution which will most probably be a Thread usage.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a timer with an anonymous method instead, Thread.Sleep is (in most cases) evil...

```
System.Threading.Timer timer;
timer = new Timer((cs) =>
    {
        ...asynchronous send here
        timer.Dispose();
    }, null, 2000, Timeout.Inifinite);
```

This means that the code inside the brackets will be run once after 2000 milliseconds.

The `timer.Dispose()` line is very important, there is a limit to how many undisposed timers you can have.

Comment: How can i know the number of undisposed timers i can have? is this number the same as the number of threads my application can create? Actually i want to know if your suggestion creates a new thread for waiting operation. If so, very similarly to Thread.Sleep method, i guess it will decrease the performance very much.

Comment: In tests I've performed I think it's about 50-60 timers that can be active at the same time, so you may have to use some throttling if you're going to make a 100 requests. And yes, each anonymous method will execute on its own thread, but the thread will have a short lifespan since all you do on it is an async send and a Dispose. If you put a Thread.Sleep(2000) on a thread you guarantee that it will live for at least 2000 ms while doing nothing useful during most of its lifetime.

Comment: OK I believe your solution is better than Thread.Sleep. However, i thought there would be a solution better than thread or timer waits. I thought there could be a SendAsync function overload which accepts a delay parameter somehow and waits for the delayed time before sending the data internally. This would be useful.